# refresh my current time on each 6 seconds

Tags: javascript

I want to refresh div on each 6 second? I am using this code but why my time is not refreshing ?
after page reload it shows current time.

```
setInterval(function() {
          var d = new Date(),        
            h = d.getHours(),
            m = d.getMinutes();
              if(h < 10) h = '0' + h; 
              if(m < 10) m = '0' + m;
                      
              $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function(){ 
                $(this).attr({'value': h + ':' + m});
              });
       }, 3000);
```

Comment: what selector `input[type="time"][value="now"]` mean dude? i think just fix selector and it working correct

Answer (score 0):

because after first change `inupt` value changed,
`$('input[type="time"][value="now"]')` is not working because there is no input tag has value "now"

try this

```js
setInterval(function() {
          var d = new Date(),        
            h = d.getHours(),
            m = d.getMinutes();
              if(h < 10) h = '0' + h; 
              if(m < 10) m = '0' + m;
                      
              $('input[type="time"]').each(function(){ 
                $(this).attr({'value': h + ':' + m});
              });
       }, 3000);
```